# Observe mounted Folder and integrate new files

Tags: structr

I'd like to observe a mounted folder in structr.
Files get pushed into that folder through a non-structr cron job, so they may change pretty often.
I mounted a folder (/var/structr) through structr UI. If I create a file through structr UI I can access it on the server's filesystem via shell/cli.
But if I create a file through shell/cli it doesn't show up in structr.
I'm using structr CE.
Is that even possible to archive with structr?

Tanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, obviously the function for observing a folder's content (find.contains) is not included in structr's CE.
It's part of advanced scripting module.